# How to get s subset sum to print out the integers it used (python)

Tags: python, subset-sum

So here is the code that i have so far. It works and returns true if the sum exists but i cant seem for the life of me to find a way for it to print out the integers it used to find the sum. Is there a way i can re write it to get it to do that along with true or how should i write the code so it can do that?

```
from itertools import combinations

def com_subset_sum(seq, target):
    if target == 0 or target in seq:
        return True

    for r in range(2, len(seq)):
        for subset in combinations(seq, r):
            if sum(subset) == target:
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `print` to see it's content:

Example:

```
from itertools import combinations

def com_subset_sum(seq, target):
    if target == 0 or target in seq:
        return True

    for r in range(len(seq),1,-1):
        for subset in combinations(seq, r):
            if sum(subset) == target:
                print subset
                return True
    return False


print com_subset_sum([1,3,5,1,6,8,7],10)
```

**output:**

```
(1, 3, 5, 1)
True
```

Comment: hmm can you show me how id implement that into my code when i tried it just printed out the whole list of integers and the sum of them instead of the target sum and the integers used for reach it. Ex: if my list was [1,2,3,4,5] and my target was 8 id want it to print out just [1,2,5]

Comment: yes and no. when i tried that and i gave it the list [1,3,5,1,6,8,7] and the target 10 it printed out [3,7] and i was hoping it would print out [1,3,5,1] since that is the first sequence that equals 10 even though it uses more numbers if that makes sense

Comment: @user2292439 the problem is that you're using a range from 2 to len(seq), small to large. You should use `range(len(seq),2,-1)` to get bigger subsets first.

Comment: alright awesome thank you that works very well. now my only question is when i give it a target value of 4 why does it return false instead of (1,3) or if i enter a target of 8 why would it return true but not give me the values?

Comment: @user2292439 I made a simple mistake there: `range(len(seq),1,-1)`, it should work fine now.

Comment: awesome thank you that fixes the first part but still the problem remains when i give it a target of 8, it will return true but still wont give the values

Comment: @user2292439 That's because 8 is already in the seq, just add a `print` statement in your first `if` condition. Did you write this code yourself?

Comment: alright that makes sense im dumb thank you again man you were a huge help

Answer (score 0):

What about something like

```
def ssum(numbers, target):
    return [x for r in xrange(2,len(numbers)) for x in combinations(numbers,r) if sum(x)==target]
```